# How to get JWT token decoded from get request in node api

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt

I'm sending JWT tokens accross requests for authorization, however I can't seem to get the token decode each time. It works with one method but not the other. The first snippet gives a "decoded" token result from the server side, however the second one doesn't.

```js
public async getAllUsers(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      const payload = req["decoded"]; // gives the token decoded
      if (payload) {
        let users: ILoginResult = await UserData.getAllUsers(payload);
        res.status(users.status).send(users.result);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: e.toString() });
    }
  }
```

```js
  public async getAccountDetails(req: Request, res: Response) {
    try {
      const user = req["decoded"]; // always undefined
      let details: IDetails = await AccountData.getAccountDetails(name);
      res.status(200).send(details);
    } catch (e) {
      let err = e.toString();
      res.status(500).send({ error: err });
    }
  }
```

The request from postman are included a `bearer token` which is provided at login and used throughout other parts of the app. Not sure why it works in the one but not the other. Would really appreciate if someone could better explain what's going on here and/or provide tips, advice, suggestions.

edit - adding request details

get request to: `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/account`
with a token: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzc5OTUwMjUsImV4cCI6MTU3ODE2NzgyNSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdCJ9.--msLba1VPs4Nv_B9YL6fk2DFHkQCgiVvDJFPt_UnDk`

The `decoded` property was used in a tutorial I was following that seemed to be added from the server side but was poorly explained and I haven't found a good alternative/explanation. I don't think it has any middleware either. Very much open to alt methods.

Comment: Have you used a middleware before getAccountDetails in the request handler? I'm thinking about how is the property 'decoded' set up in the request object?...

Comment: @ranieribt I was wrong, there totally is a middleware working on the route which seems to have been the problem since it created the the decoded property. Thanks!

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I believe the auth with Vue and Node one from Scotch.IO although I picked and chose from multiple since I couldn't find everything I wanted in one.

Comment: So is your problem resolved?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes it is, I posted an answer to better explain how in case someone else makes a similar mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions from the comments I was able to find a missing piece in the route that creates the `decoded` property which is being used here. By adding the middleware to the router the request works as expected:

```js
import express from "express";
import UserController from "../controllers/UserController";
import valid from "../utils/ValidateToken";

export default (router: express.Router) => {
  router
    .route("/users")
    .post(UserController.addUser)
    .get(valid.validateToken, UserController.getAllUsers);

  router.route("/login").post(UserController.loginUser);
  router.route("/account").get(valid.validateToken, UserController.getAccountDetails);
};
```

The `valid.validateToken` was missing which is the bit that generates the decoded object from the JWT being passed. Moral of the story, always double check everything. Thanks to all who commented/answered!